# My /kill @e isn't killing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to destroy dropped Oak Planks, and my command is:

```
/kill @e[type=item,tag={id:"minecraft:oak_planks"}]
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: If you seriously gave something the tag `{id:"minecraft:oak_planks"}`, then you need to escape the quotation marks and put the entire name into quotation marks. But you probably want to match NBT instead, in which case you need the `nbt` argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `[tag=]` you use in the selector isn't the same with the NBT tag `{tag:{}}`, you need to use `[nbt={}]` instead of `[tag=]` for it to work.

Here's the fixed version:

`/kill @e[type=item,nbt={id:"minecraft:oak_planks"}]`

Comment: Ty so much for taking the time to answer me everybody!